# List or regex of JavaScript commands, functions and built-ins

Tags: javascript

Does anyone have a simple text list or regex of all default JavaScript commands, functions, build-ins and/or keywords?

I am writing an AI to detect malicious web calls. To make it easier for the AI to learn I am pre detecting SQL, Unix etc.

What I have:

```
const sql_keywords = /(?:alter|begin|create|delete|drop|exec|rollback|update|select)/gi;
const sql_others = /(?:1=1|ALL|AS|ASC|CONCAT|CURRENT|DELAY|DISTINCT|FROM|GROUP|BY|HAVING|WINDOW|UNION|INTERSECT|EXCEPT|ORDER|DESC|USING|NULLS|FIRST|LAST|LIMIT|OFFSET|ROW|ROWS|FETCH|NEXT|ONLY|NO|KEY|SHARE|OF|NOWAIT|LATERAL|NATURAL|TABLE|RETURNING|WAITFOR|WHERE)/gi;
```

```
const unix_commands = /\b(?:admin|alias|ar|asa|at|awk|basename|batch|bc|bg|c99|cc|cal|cat|cd|cflow|chgrp|chmod|chown|cksum|cmp|comm|command|compress|cp|crontab|csplit|ctags|cut|cxref|date|dd|delta|df|diff|dirname|du|echo|ed|env|ex|expand|expr|false|fc|fg|file|find|fold|fort77|fuser|gencat|get|getconf|getopts|grep|hash|head|iconv|id|ipcrm|ipcs|jobs|join|kill|lex|link|ln|locale|localedef|logger|logname|lp|ls|m4|mailx|make|man|mesg|mkdir|mkfifo|more|mv|newgrp|nice|nl|nm|nohup|od|paste|patch|pathchk|pax|pr|printf|prs|ps|pwd|qalter|qdel|qhold|qmove|qmsg|qrerun|qrls|qselect|qsig|qstat|qsub|read|renice|rm|rmdel|rmdir|sact|sccs|sed|sh|sleep|sort|split|strings|strip|stty|tabs|tail|talk|tee|test|time|touch|tput|tr|true|tsort|tty|type|ulimit|umask|unalias|uname|uncompress|unexpand|unget|uniq|unlink|uucp|uudecode|uuencode|uustat|uux|val|vi|wait|wc|what|who|write|xargs|yacc|zcat)\b/gi
const unix_others = /\b(?:group|passwd|shadow)\b/gi
const ambiguous = /\b(?:id|nl|crontab|date|file|find)\b/gi
```

What I want:

```
const js_commands = /\b(?:alert|...|...|...|...)\b/gi
```

I ask this question because you can find results for SQL and Unix relatively quickly in Google. For JavaScript, I haven't found anything comparable in a hurry.

It does not have to be complete.

Comment: Is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) what you're looking for?

Comment: Aah, you want to find ALL javascript commands... Well, there isn't a simple regex for that and to find a list of that would be nearly impossible... However detecting () in some clever way might put you on your way to detect javascript commands... Otherwise [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar) might help you out

Comment: You seem to be looking for properties/methods of the Window object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: extract the data from the typescript definitions file for browsers, and a keyword list?

Comment: Btw i don't know what you are trying to do, but you should know, that in javascript, there is no need to actually have any of these words as plaintext in the source. Something like `(function() { return this; })()[[101, 118, 97, 108].map(e => String.fromCharCode(e)).join("")]('alert("where is eval?")');`

Comment: @ASDFGerte It doesn't have to be perfect. It's just about training the AI. The AI is not stupid. Moreover, I decode as much as possible before the analysis. Do you have a link to the typescript definitions file of a browser?

Comment: You can find related files from [the github page](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/lib), and read how it works e.g. [here](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/lib.d.ts). (edit: changed github link to parent folder, as that contains many of the related files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const js_commands = /\b(?:abstract|afterprint|AggregateError|alert|animationcancel|animationend|animationiteration|animationstart|arguments|Array|ArrayBuffer|async|AsyncFunction|AsyncGenerator|AsyncGeneratorFunction|Atomics|await|beforeprint|beforeunload|BigInt|BigInt64Array|BigUint64Array|Block|blur|Boolean|boolean|break|byte|cancelAnimationFrame|cancelIdleCallback|case|catch|char|class|clearImmediate|clipboardchange|close|confirm|const|continue|convertPointFromNodeToPage|convertPointFromPageToNode|copy|copy_event.clipboardData|crypto|customElements|cut|cut_event.clipboardData|DataView|Date|debugger|decodeURI|decodeURIComponent|default|delete|devicemotion|deviceorientation|devicePixelRatio|dialogArguments|do|document|DOMContentLoaded|double|each|else|Empty|encodeURI|encodeURIComponent|enum|error|eval|EvalError|event|export|extends|external|false|final|finally|find|float|Float32Array|Float64Array|focus|for|frameElement|frames|fullScreen|function|gamepadconnected|gamepaddisconnected|Generator|GeneratorFunction|get|getAttention|getAttentionWithCycleCount|getComputedStyle|getDefaultComputedStyle|getSelection|globalStorage|globalThis|goto|hashchange|history|home|if|implements|import|import.meta|in|Infinity|innerHeight|innerWidth|instanceof|int|Int16Array|Int32Array|Int8Array|interface|InternalError|Intl|Intl.Collator|Intl.DateTimeFormat|Intl.DisplayNames|Intl.ListFormat|Intl.Locale|Intl.NumberFormat|Intl.PluralRules|Intl.RelativeTimeFormat|isFinite|isNaN|isSecureContext|JSON|label|languagechange|length|let|load|localStorage|location|locationbar|long|Map|matchMedia|Math|maximize|menubar|message|messageerror|minimize|moveBy|moveTo|mozAnimationStartTime|mozInnerScreenX|mozInnerScreenY|mozPaintCount|name|NaN|native|navigator|new|null|Number|Object|of|offline|onappinstalled|onbeforeinstallprompt|ondevicelight|ondevicemotion|ondeviceorientation|ondeviceorientationabsolute|ondeviceproximity|ongamepadconnected|ongamepaddisconnected|online|onorientationchange|onpaint|onuserproximity|onvrdisplayactivate|onvrdisplayblur|onvrdisplayconnect|onvrdisplaydeactivate|onvrdisplaydisconnect|onvrdisplayfocus|onvrdisplaypointerrestricted|onvrdisplaypointerunrestricted|onvrdisplaypresentchange|open|openDialog|opener|orientation|orientationchange|origin|outerHeight|outerWidth|OverconstrainedError|package|pagehide|pageshow|pageXOffset|pageYOffset|parent|parseFloat|parseInt|paste|paste_event.clipboardData|performance|personalbar|pkcs11|popstate|postMessage|preventDefault|print|private|Promise|prompt|Proxy|public|RangeError|ReferenceError|Reflect|RegExp|rejectionhandled|requestAnimationFrame|requestFileSystem|requestIdleCallback|resize|resizeBy|resizeTo|resolveLocalFileSystemURL|return|returnValue|routeEvent|screen|screenLeft|screenTop|screenX|screenY|scroll|scrollbars|scrollBy|scrollByLines|scrollByPages|scrollMaxX|scrollMaxY|scrollTo|ScrollToOptions|scrollX|scrollY|self|sessionStorage|set|Set|setCursor|setImmediate|setResizable|SharedArrayBuffer|short|showModalDialog|sizeToContent|speechSynthesis|static|status|statusbar|stop|storage|String|super|switch|Symbol|synchronized|SyntaxError|target|this|throw|throws|toolbar|top|transfer|transient|transitioncancel|transitionend|transitionrun|transitionstart|true|try|TypeError|typeof|Uint16Array|Uint32Array|Uint8Array|Uint8ClampedArray|undefined|unhandledrejection|unload|updateCommands|URIError|value|var|visualViewport|void|volatile|vrdisplayactivate|vrdisplayblur|vrdisplayconnect|vrdisplaydeactivate|vrdisplaydisconnect|vrdisplayfocus|vrdisplaypointerrestricted|vrdisplaypointerunrestricted|vrdisplaypresentchange|WeakMap|WeakSet|WebAssembly|WebAssembly.CompileError|WebAssembly.Instance|WebAssembly.LinkError|WebAssembly.Memory|WebAssembly.Module|WebAssembly.RuntimeError|WebAssembly.Table|while|window|with|yield)\b/gi
```

Sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Please comment if you find a missing default JS command, function, built-in (I am only interested in key "words").